# How to link .dylib libraries after installing an application

Tags: macos, packaging, dynamic-linking, dylib, apple-m1

This is my first time creating an installer for an application and I need some advice.

This application depends on `A.dylib`, and `A.dylib` depends on two other libraries: `libstdc++.6.dylib` and `libgomp.1.dylib` which all come from the gcc folder. When I do `otool -L` on `A.dylib`, this is what I get :

```
A.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libstdc++.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.28.0)
/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/libgomp.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
```

Which means that if these two libraries aren't in there, the application won't launch at all. So my problem is with the installer, am I supposed to install `libstdc++.6.dylib` and `libgomp.1.dylib` in `/opt/homebrew/opt/gcc/lib/gcc/10/` for the user? Even if they don't have a gcc installed there, or at all?

Another option is to install the libraries under say `/Library/Application Support/`, but then this would mean that the path `A.dylib` is linked to won't be correct anymore. How do I change the linking path automatically after I install those libraries? What is the best way to go beyond this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: ..... How to correctly tell GCC Compiler where to find another static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268814/dyld-library-not-loaded-how-to-correctly-tell-gcc-compiler-where-to-find)

Comment: Neither of your options, although they may work, are what you want.  The best way is to bundle.

Comment: @RichardBarber could you go a bit more in detail what do you mean by bundling?

Comment: @Siguza `install_name_tool` is a great tool for this, thank you. Unfortunately, I run into a problem when I use it on 3rd party libraries (from gcc folder), it invalides the code signature. I saw at the end of your answer you mentioned it briefly, which seemed interesting. Do you know any site/documentation that goes a bit more on depth on how to use codesign for this specific situation?

Comment: To note that this is my first time working on Mac and my first time seeing the concept of codesigning, so I'm a complete beginner for this scenario.

Comment: @LuisAngelUrenaLopez depends on what kind of signature you need. In general, `codesign -f` can replace an existing signature. For an ad-hoc signature, `codesign -f -s - [file]` should do the trick... otherwise see `man codesign`. But if you need to keep the signing identity of a 3rd-party, then you simply cannot modify the dylib. That's what the code signature ensures.

Comment: @Siguza I understand that's what the code signature ensures, makes total sense. This means I need to keep the 3rd party libraries untouched, which raises a problem for me. Since I'm moving all the libraries inside the .app, that means the path it's linked to will be wrong once they're moved. Since I can't modify that path, do you recommend me to install these libraries on the user's computer exactly on the path the dependencies are pointing to? Or is there a cleaner way to do this without invalidating the code signature?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html The application bundle structure.