# dlopen Library not loaded: @rpath/shared.framework/shared no such file

Tags: swift, xcode, kotlin-multiplatform, dylib

I know there is many similar questions has been asked, and I do follow many of them, still without luck.

`otool -l /../iosAppUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/iosAppUITests.xctest/iosAppUITests`

```
Load command 26
          cmd LC_LOAD_WEAK_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name @rpath/libXCTestSwiftSupport.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 08:00:02 1970
      current version 21250.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 27
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/lib/swift/libswiftFoundation.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 08:00:02 1970
      current version 1.0.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 28
          cmd LC_RPATH
      cmdsize 40
         path @loader_path/Frameworks (offset 12)
```

##### Xcode console log

[image]

The shared framework is created successfully in path below.

`/../Debug-iphonesimulator/iosApp.app/Frameworks/shared.framework/shared`

But @rpath searched on a slight different path without `/iosApp.app/Frameworks/`

`/../Debug-iphonesimulator/shared.framework/shared' (no such file)`

[image]

Any help with how to solve this path issue above would be helpful!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: ..... How to correctly tell GCC Compiler where to find another static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268814/dyld-library-not-loaded-how-to-correctly-tell-gcc-compiler-where-to-find)

Comment: @Siguza, thanks for this, I'm looking into it now, though I was struck on some C grammer, Googling...

Comment: @Siguza, I just could understand a little bit what you are writing in that post. It is kind of deep for me. But anyway appreciate for your reply.

Comment: Hi @Siguza, I update my post to include more specific info, basicly I think that @rpath try to find the shared lib on the level same with `iosApp.app`, instead of find it into `iosApp.app` package. Would you mind to give me some hint on how to solve this problem, I'd like to learn.