# Library not loaded: @rpath/somelib.dylib

Tags: swift, xcode, dylib

I need to integrate a `.dylib` library and `.h` headers into iOS project to call its methods from Swift. It's [illegal](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2435/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017543-CH1-TROUBLESHOOTING-BUNDLE_ERRORS) to add a `.dylib` file in iOS project, so I've tried to make a few workarounds:

- Create a `.xcframework` with embedded `.dylib` and it's headers
- Create a `.framework` with with embedded library binary, created using [lipo](https://ss64.com/osx/lipo.html) command

Both workarounds compile successfully, but crashes when trying to run on a real device with message:

```
dyld[38413]: Library not loaded: @rpath/somelib.dylib
  Referenced from: <6519D385-F3EB-3454-8CA0-02BF7E536629> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D1A6139C-EC53-46DA-A647-4A520E4F112C/TestApp.app/TestApp
  Reason: tried: '/usr/lib/system/introspection/somelib.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D1A6139C-EC53-46DA-A647-4A520E4F112C/TestApp.app/Frameworks/somelib.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D1A6139C-EC53-46DA-A647-4A520E4F112C/TestApp.app/Frameworks/somelib.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS@rpath/somelib.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D1A6139C-EC53-46DA-A647-4A520E4F112C/TestApp.app/Frameworks/somelib.dylib' (errno=2), '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D1A6139C-EC53-46DA-A647-4A520E4F112C/TestApp.app/Frameworks/somelib.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/local/lib/somelib.dylib' (errno=2), '/usr/lib/somelib.dylib' (errno=2, not in dyld cache)
```

My guess is that some paths are setted up incorrectly, but I don't know how to fix that.

Here's content of my `.h` headers file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void ms_init(int width, int height);
void ms_draw();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I found a [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66284977/11919563) to almost the same question, but the difference is that I use a `.h` headers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: ..... How to correctly tell GCC Compiler where to find another static library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268814/dyld-library-not-loaded-how-to-correctly-tell-gcc-compiler-where-to-find)

Comment: @Siguza not really, because your answer contains `.c` headers, and I got a `.h` headers. I can't find a way to implement those commands for my type of headers. I will update my answer to show how they look like.

Comment: Neither `.c` nor `.h` files matter for this, and editing them won't change anything. I just needed something to demonstrate things on. What really matters is the install name used in the `LC_ID_DYLIB` command of your dylib and in `LC_LOAD_DYLIB` in everything that links against it.