# How does one consistently set rpath on a dynamic library and compile time?

Tags: perl, dll, shared-libraries, dylib, cmark

I spent an inordinate amount of time this past week adding comprehensive OS, Perl Version, and cmark version tests to the Perl CommonMark module ([pull request](https://github.com/nwellnhof/perl-commonmark/pull/12)). Most of my time was spent trying to get macOS and Windows to find each version of cmark built and installed in a custom location.

On macOS, setting `INC=-"I/cmark-$version/include" LIBS=-"L/cmark-$version/lib -lcmark"` was sufficient to build successfully, but for some versions of Perl it was unable to find cmark at runtime. Reviewing [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66284977/79202) and a few other resources, I eventually got it to always find the library by adding this line to the [build script](https://github.com/nwellnhof/perl-commonmark/blob/7efa51ae1fbe1b9f3c74fa5b9a8c0c0b1ef74881/.github/bin/build.sh):

```bash
[[ "${OSTYPE}" == "darwin"* ]] && install_name_tool -add_rpath "${PREFIX}/lib" blib/arch/auto/CommonMark/CommonMark.bundle || true
```

Adding the `rpath` this way works, although it fails in some instances when the `rpath` *already exists*!. Hence `|| true`.

I'm not sure why builds with some Perl/ExtUtils::MakeMaker versions add the `rpath` and some don't. I tried all sorts of incantations to get it to be added every time, for example `OTHERLDFLAGS=-Wl,-rpath,/cmark-$version/lib`, to no avail.

What is the correct way to always include the path to the dynamic library at compile time? Ideally there would be an OS-neutral way to do so.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/issues/402

Comment: *"but for some versions of Perl it was unable to find cmark at runtime."* Can you provide a simple example that shows which version of perl this happens for? Then we can try to reproduce.

Comment: I agree that using `install_name_tool` should in principle not be necessary, but I do not have time to look into this right now. But the question is important (seeing all those GitHub issues about problems with linking when trying to compile a Perl module on macOS) and thus definitively needs a clear answer.

Comment: @HåkonHægland This [5.20 build](https://github.com/theory/perl-commonmark/actions/runs/6113015043/job/16591639670) compiles but fails to find the library at runtime. Also [5.18](https://github.com/theory/perl-commonmark/actions/runs/6113836805/job/16594143130) , and [5.16](https://github.com/theory/perl-commonmark/actions/runs/6115939348/job/16600360712), as well as [5.32 on Windows](https://github.com/theory/perl-commonmark/actions/runs/6132225869/job/16642899009)

Comment: @HåkonHægland Do you think installing the latest EU:MM will fix the issue on macOS? Do I need to set `LC_RPATH` or `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (or pass either one to `Makefile.PL`)?

Comment: @HåkonHægland upgrading EU::MM does indeed [fix the issue](https://github.com/nwellnhof/perl-commonmark/compare/7efa51ae1fbe1b9f3c74fa5b9a8c0c0b1ef74881..72764ff4b39997b76c887b7f27ba5e495ef66dee) on macOS, thanks! Now for Windows, as in [this 5.20 build](https://github.com/theory/perl-commonmark/actions/runs/6147728099/job/16679857798) and [this 5.32 build](https://github.com/theory/perl-commonmark/actions/runs/6147728099/job/16679856261).

Comment: Also [this 5.38 Windows build](https://github.com/theory/perl-commonmark/actions/runs/6148027513/job/16680817179) where it can't find the library at compile time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer, ultimately, is **update to the latest ExtUtils::MakeMaker.**

As [@håkon-hægland](/users/2173773/h%C3%A5kon-h%C3%A6gland) points out in his comment on the OP, he's investigated this  quite a bit, as documented in [ExtUtils-MakeMaker issue #402](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/issues/402). A [pull request](https://github.com/Perl-Toolchain-Gang/ExtUtils-MakeMaker/pull/403) merged in September 2021 was his attempt to address the issue; it was released in [v7.64](https://metacpan.org/release/BINGOS/ExtUtils-MakeMaker-7.68/changes#L48) in December 2021.

Upgrading to the latest version fixed the issue completely, so I was able to remove the call to `install_name_tool`. Anyone testing on macOS 10.4 or earlier will need v7.66 to avoid the setting of `rpath`, however.