# dyld[22230]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2 Reason: no LC_RPATH's found

Tags: c, macos, zsh, sdl-2, apple-m1

Operating system MacOS Sonoma 14.3.1, processor Apple M1. I faced the problem of running the compiled program. As it was written in the "title", I got this console output after run executable file:

```
> ./game
dyld[22230]: Library not loaded: @rpath/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
  Referenced from: <(random symbols, I don't think show it is a good idea)> /Users/(my username)/Downloads/game-prototype/game
  Reason: no LC_RPATH's found
  zsh: abort   ./game
```

I have installed the SDL2 library with its add-ons both manually in the `Library/Frameworks` folder and through homebrew (`opt/homebrew/Cellar`), but the homebrew-version never worked. Perhaps the problem with the homebrew-version is due to the fact that I did not start this program and started to work only after I added `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH` in `~/.zprofile`. I can't really understand why it doesn't work.

The program was compiled by the following command:

```
clang main.c global.c on-create/*.c clock/*.c active/*.c -I/Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Headers -F/Library/Frameworks -framework SDL2 -framework SDL2_image -framework SDL2_mixer -framework SDL2_ttf -o game
```

From a previously specified error, I opened the executable file (`SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2`) to check its functionality, and the console output was:

```
zsh: exec format error: /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Tell me, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `-rpath /Library/Frameworks` to your clang invocation should fix the issue.

Alternatively, changing the install name of the framework, re-signing it and then recompiling your binary would also fix it:

```
install_name_tool -id /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2 /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
codesign -s - -f /Library/Frameworks/SDL2.framework/Versions/A/SDL2
```

For a more in-depth explanation of install names, see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66268814/dyld-library-not-loaded-how-to-correctly-tell-gcc-compiler-where-to-find/66284977#66284977).