# .dylib not Found Trying to Open the Program After Being Generated by PAServer

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, dylib, delphi-12-athens, paserver

I use FireMonkey to generate executables for MacOS-64.

I'm developing software that uses a third-party dylib, I call it like this:

```
{$IFDEF OSX64}cdecl; external 'R_mylib.a.dylib' name 'LibCall';
{$ENDIF}
```

So far so good. I compile it and everything works. The program opens on Mac through PAServer perfectly.

But now my problem begins. When I close the program on the Mac and try to open it again with a double click, it does not find my .dylib and consequently does not open the program, but if I click on Show Contents and navigate to the MacOs folder and There, double click on the EXE, then it opens.

Could anyone help me with this problem?
I'm using Delphi 12, PAServer 23, MacOs Sonoma 14.2.1.
Thank you very much.
Marcelo

I have already copied the .dylib to the /usr/local/lib folder and to the HOME folder

Result of the otool -L

```
/usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 1336.61.1)
/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 228.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 2202.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 1226.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 2202.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 64.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Metal.framework/Versions/A/Metal (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 341.35.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/MetalKit.framework/Versions/A/MetalKit (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 161.0.0)
R_libClientAPI64Mac.a.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 1774.2.3)
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
```

Comment: Can you add to your post the output of running `otool -L` against the binary in `.app/Contents/MacOS/`?

Comment: Post edited with the result of the otool -L

Comment: Okay, it looks like `R_libClientAPI64Mac.a.dylib` is the issue, what with not having a proper install name. There's multiple ways to fix this, but I'm unfamiliar with Delphi or PAServer, so I can't tell which would be the most appropriate. If you have some 15 minutes, I suggest giving [this post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66284977/2302862) a read, where I explain in detail the underlying issue and the different ways to fix it.